# fstat: st_atime and st_mtime not a member?

Tags: c

I am doing an `fstat` on my file descriptor and dumping that into a `struct stat`.  I read the documentation for `fstat` (link below) and it claims there are members `st_atime` and `st_mtime`.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html

GCC let's me compile, but stepping through GDB, I cannot print out those members (i.e. I can print every other member).  GDB claims they don't exist.

In fact, when I print out the `struct stat`, `st_atime` is spelt `st_atim` (i.e. same thing with `st_mtime`).  Then it looks like it's a tuple or something because it holds two values, `tv_sec` and `tv_nsec`.

Does anyone know why `GDB` is claiming they don't exist?

Also, does anyone know how to pass it to `memcpy`?  I am using `C90`.

This is the line of code it complains about saying I can't pass a `time_t` in here.  How would I cast it to make this line work?

```
memcpy(&temp.otar_adate, file_statistics.st_atime, OTAR_DATE_SIZE);
```

MY OS: CentOS

Comment: I am not sure I understand the point of using `memcpy`. If the types are compatible, use assignment. If they are not compatible, `memcpy` is probably the wrong approach. However, you probably meant to pass in `&file_statistics.st_atime`.

Comment: As to *GDB claims they don't exist*, you have not specified your OS platform, and whether it is supposed to be POSIX compliant.

Comment: @jxh That was it.  I wasn't including the &.  Hah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, at least certain versions, `st_atime` and some other time fields in `struct stat` are inside `struct timespec` and contain proper timestamps with full nanosecond precision. On those systems `st_atime` is a define to something else. On my CentOS machine it is defined to `st_atim.tv_sec`.

Throw your code into the preprocessor to see what it is on your system:

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <sys/stat.h>

void
foo(void)
{
    struct stat st;

    (void)st.st_atime;
}
$ cc -E foo.c | tail -7
void
foo(void)
{
 struct stat st;

 (void)st.st_atim.tv_sec;
}
```

Gdb doesn't know about preprocessor defines, so it can't know how your code got preprocessed. It only knows about the real definition of the struct.